# Chai deep equal not working on URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, chai

I'm trying to test if my `URLSearchParams` are correct with chai's `to.deep.equal` option but it returns `true` (is equal) when it shouldn't.

See the running code at https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-qx7qra?file=index.test.js

Let's assume that we're testing this function:

```js
function getIncorrectParams() {
  return new URLSearchParams({
    from: '2020',
    to: '2021',
    ids: ['abc-1'],
  });
}
```

If I write:

```js
test('via string', () => {
  expect(getIncorrectParams().toString()).not.to.equal(
    new URLSearchParams({
      from: '2020',
      to: '2021',
      ids: ['abc-1', 'abc-2'],
    }).toString()
  );
});
```

Chai correctly notices that the strings are not the same, good. But as soon as I remove the `toString` and test with:

```js
test('via deep equal', () => {
  expect(getIncorrectParams()).not.to.deep.equal(
    new URLSearchParams({
      from: '2020',
      to: '2021',
      ids: ['abc-1', 'abc-2'],
    })
  );
});
```

It claims that the assertion failed because the two objects are "equal". Note if you actually go ahead and run the example, the debug output clearly shows that there are differences!

And the `deep.equal` property works if I use "normal" object. See this example where I convert the `URLSearchParams` to a "plain object" first:

```js
test('deep equal plain objects', () => {
  expect(Object.fromEntries(getIncorrectParams().entries())).not.to.deep.equal({
    from: '2020',
    to: '2021',
    ids: ['abc-1', 'abc-2'],
  });
});
```

Comment: If you guys think it's a bug please leave a comment and I'll open an issue on the repo :)

Comment: Asking out of curiosity, you are using Jest with Chai for assertions. Why not use Jest?

I also suspect that it's a bug with Chai because Jest is behaving correctly (both with `.toBe()` and `.toEqual()`. Chai did compare other API constructors (e.g. `Map`, `Set` and even `URL`) properly.

Comment: @SimonIfergan I've started to use chai recently because the assertions are way better than the ones of jest. The debug output is brilliant (if something doesn't match), you can provide custom messages if a test fails, etc, etc.

Comment: https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/1415